# Why does underscore comes under \w?

Tags: regex

This may be a theoretical question.

Why does underscore `_` comes under `\w` in regex and not under `\W`

I hope this isn't primarily opinion based, because there should be a reason.

Citation would be great, if at all available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Wikipedia's [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) article (emphasis mine):

> An additional non-POSIX class understood by some tools is `[:word:]`, which is usually defined as `[:alnum:]` plus underscore. ***This reflects the fact that in many programming languages these are the characters that may be used in identifiers***.

In [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) and [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), this **non-standard** class is represented by `\w` (and characters outside this class are represented by `\W`).

Answer (score 2):

`\w` matches any single code point that has any of the following properties:

- `\p{GC=Alphabetic}` (letters and some more unicode points)
- `\p{GC=Mark}` (Mark: Spacing, non-spacing, enclosing)
- `\p{GC=Connector_Punctuation}` (e.g. underscore)
- `\p{GC=Decimal_Number}` (numbers and other variants of numbers)
- `\p{Join_Control}` (code points U+0200C and U+0200D)

These properties are used in the composition of programming language identifiers in scripts. For instance<sup>[[1]](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#word)</sup>:

> The Connector Punctuation (`\p{GC=Connector_Punctuation}`) is added in for programming language identifiers, thus adding "_" and similar characters.

There is a<sup>[[2]](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Default_Identifier_Syntax)</sup>:

> general intent that an identifier consists of a string of characters beginning with a letter or an ideograph, and followed by any number of letters, ideographs, digits, or underscores.

The `\p{Join_Control}` was actually recently added to the character class `\w` as well and [here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2012/07/msg189962.html)'s a message that perl devs exchanged for its implementation, supporting my earlier mention that `\w` is used to compose identifiers.

Comment: Does not answer the question. The OP seems to be fully aware that `\W` includes exactly whatever `\w` does not include, and in fact used that relationship to ask his or her question. You wrote: "The basic definition of \w being [A-Za-z0-9_]" - the question by the OP is *why* that is the basic definition of `\w`, with respect to the underscore.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks. I didn't realise the title was that different from the body of the question. Changed the content of my answer accordingly.